# Tooltip shows different text on hovering over button content

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, tooltip, staticresource

I am under a situation where i have button and set the style to static resource (CreateNewItemButtonStyle here) of this button.
I also have a tooltip and i display some text whenever i hover mouse over this tooltip ("SelectAllLines" here).
It dsiplays tooltip text correctly  when i hover mouse over button area, excluding the content area(I mean when i hover on content "AL" it shows "AL" on tooltip, it should't do that, it should show 
only "SelectAllLines" on entire button area tooltip).

I figured out it is because of the style i am using.

But how to have same text on my tooltip on my entire button area which i have set by doing ToolTip="Selected Lines"

```
<Button
    x:Name="AllLinesButtonX"
    Background="{StaticResource FlowPowderBlackBrush}"
    Click="AllLinesButtonX_OnClick"
    Command="{Binding AllLinesCommand}"
    Content="AL"
    MouseRightButtonUp="SelectGeometryToggleButton_OnMouseRightButtonUp"
    Style="{StaticResource CreateNewItemButtonStyle}"  //If i remove this line it stops showing "AL", just shows "SelectedAllLines" which is the correct behavior
    ToolTip="SelectAllLines"
</Button>
```

Here is style's key:

```
 <Style x:Key="CreateNewItemButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisualStyle}" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
<Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="10" />
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
<Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
<Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ContentPresenter
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ActiveButtonBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ActiveBorderBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ActiveButtonBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ActiveBorderBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: i have tried the above code and dont seem to have any problem with it.. it's working fine..

Answer (score 0):

Set `IsHitTestVisible="false"` to `ContentPresenter` in `ControlTemplate` of your button style.

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible(v=vs.110).aspx